# Changing boolean in actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, boolean, actionlistener

I have an actionlistener on a button that is to change a boolean called flood to true when clicked, this is then used in an if statement to call a method that will change a frame. My problem is nothing is happening when the button is clicked. I am using a debug log to check for the problem but I'm stumped.

```
public class Stop_The_Flood extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
final Button StopTheFlood = new Button("Stop The Flood!");
boolean flood = false;


public Stop_The_Flood(char[][] array) {
    setTitle("Stop The Flood!");
    setSize(1024,768);
    
    //Container panel
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
    //map panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 900));
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = array[0].length;
    gbc.gridheight = array.length;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    //Button Panel
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    g.gridwidth = 1;
    g.gridheight = 1;
    g.gridx = 8;
    g.gridy = 15;
    g.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    buttonPanel.setSize(350,350);
    
    //Add to everything to frame
    getContentPane().add(container);
    container.add(panel, gbc);
    container.add(buttonPanel, g);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
   
    
    StopTheFlood.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    StopTheFlood.addActionListener(this); 
    JLabel[][] labelArray = new JLabel[array.length][array[0].length];
    
    //Initialize JLabel array with the array that contains the data
    labels(panel, labelArray, array);
    
    buttonPanel.add(StopTheFlood);
    setVisible(true);
    
    if(flood == true) {
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Stop_The_Flood");
        logger.warning("found water");
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
     flood = true;
}
```

Comment: 1) class names should not contain "_" in the name. Follow the conventions used by the JDK for class names. 2) the constructor of your class was executed when the class was created. That code will never be executed again, so the location of the "if statement" doesn't belong in the constructor. All your ActionLIstener does is change the variable. If you want something else to happen then you need to invoke some other method.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could do this?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). The `TextDemo` code will show you how to write an event driven application. When you type text into the text field and then press enter the ActionListener will be invoked and the text will be copied to the text area. I I have no idea what the point of your boolean variable is used for. If you want to do something then that code needs to be added to the ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being performed in your actionPerformed method, so you could try to create a new ClickListener class:

```
 private class Clicklistener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == StopTheFlood)
        {
           flood = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your "Stop_The_Flood" class create an object of ClickListener and add it to .addActionLister():

```
Clicklistener click= new Clicklistener();
StopTheFlood.addActionListener(click);
```

P.S don't forget to pass StopTheFlood to the ClickListener since I did not add that to the code.